# Trying to figure out bitmask for this example

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to implement quickscorer algorithm for decision trees (https://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/irwin.king/_media/presentations/sigir15bestpaper.pdf).
In here they define a bitmask for each node in a binary tree. However I couldn't figure out how it is built.
Here is an example:
[image]

Basically, the idea is that each node's mask will contain all 1s, except that it will contains 0s for all the bits whose index are leaves recheable by the left sub-tree.
So for instance, the first mask is "001111" because out of the 6 terminal leaves, leaves 0 and 1 are reachable on the left subtree, and the others (leaves 2 to 5) or reached in the right tree.
This is made more complex by the fact that in general, the trees aren't full

My question:
how do you encode the bitfields given a tree?

Comment: Hello. What is your question? Is it about how to encode the bitfields?

Comment: @Jean-MarcVolle edited the question

Answer (score 1):

Work from the bottom up, computing both a mask for what is reachable from the right child and another for the left child (even though you only end up keeping the left-child masks).

So, from your example:

- n3 would have the masks (left:110111,right:111011) directly from its leaves
- n4 would have masks (left:111101,right:111110) similarly
- n2 would AND the 2 masks for n3 to get its left mask (110011) and the 2 masks for n4 for its right mask (111100)

(n1 & n0 left as an exercise).